# Snap points shapefile to line shapefile using shapely

Tags: python, shapely, snapping, fiona

I have 2 datasets: 1) a road network shapefile which has many polylines and 2) a bus stop shapefile which has many points representing bus stops. My points shapefile has CRS of EPSG 4326 and my line shapefile has CRS of EPSG 29617. I am not sure if I should and how to convert them.

I would like to use Python only and available packages (e.g. shapely, fiona, ogr) to snap the closest bus stop that is within 45 metres to the nearest road. **Please note and see picture: there are multiple bus stops (green dots) near a road(brown line). Only the closest green dot (i.e. one green dot only) must be snapped to the brown line.**

[image]

I have written this code based on many forums which have parts of the answer. I have never coded in Python before.

```
# path of inputs 
line = "C:\folder\line.shp"
point = "C:\folder\point.shp"

# open line and points data
gdf_segments = geopandas.read_file(line)
gdf_hec_points = geopandas.read_file(point)

#join all line and points
shply_line = gdf_segments.geometry.unary_union
shply_point = gdf_hec_points.geometry.unary_union

# perform interpolation and project point to line
pt_interpolate = shply_line.interpolate(shply_line.project(shply_point))
```

The result of the code should be a new point shapefile where the points have been moved to the line.

Reference: I found the tool in ArcGIS (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm) but I cannot use any software like QGIS, GRASS, ArcGIS etc. The code needs to be in Python only.

Answer (score 15):

The methodology is called linear referencing and a solution was given by Mike T in [Coordinate of the closest point on a line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24440122) with Shapely.
There is also a recipe in the [Python Geospatial Analysis Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/python-geospatial-analysis-cookbook) ([Snapping a point to the nearest line](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781783555079/5/ch05lvl1sec43/snapping-a-point-to-the-nearest-line)
)

> "This super common spatial task is for all the GPS junkies who want their GPS coordinates to snap to an existing road" ...

The problem:

[image]

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf_segments = gpd.read_file("line.shp")
shply_line = gdf_segments.geometry.unary_union
point  = gpd.read_file('points.shp')
point.crs
{'init': 'epsg:4326'}
# reproject the points
point = point.to_crs(gdf_segments.crs)
print(point)
   id                                      geometry
0   1  POINT (165.2232667307835 -581.6023098314181)
1   2  POINT (458.0395231332805 -626.3180927932262)
2   3  POINT (807.1111194563855 -509.4800791162997)
3   4  POINT (1019.150477463845 -1181.659268662333)
4   5  POINT (74.34925616221153 -244.0702704396099)
5   6  POINT (19.53636085704784 -383.9873978914693)
```

Solution with linear referencing:

```
for i in range(len(point)):
    print(shply_line.interpolate(shply_line.project( point.geometry[i])).wkt)

POINT (158.2568242503091 -613.1561963606259)
POINT (433.554325720973 -616.258892163531)
POINT (828.8651101528822 -533.8813967264118)
POINT (981.8579545397143 -1193.379775867061)
POINT (74.34925616221147 -233.4585492227979)
POINT (18.88030104343747 -405.9654016474183)
```

New GeoDataFrame with results:

```
result = point.copy()
result['geometry'] = result.apply(lambda row: shply_line.interpolate(shply_line.project( row.geometry)), axis=1)
print(result)
   id                        geometry
0   1  POINT (158.2568242503091 -613.1561963606259)
1   2  POINT (433.554325720973 -616.258892163531)
2   3  POINT (828.8651101528822 -533.8813967264118)
3   4  POINT (981.8579545397143 -1193.379775867061)
4   5  POINT (74.34925616221147 -233.4585492227979)
5   6  POINT (18.88030104343747 -405.9654016474183)
result.to_file("new_points.shp")
```

[image]

### NEW

Buffer the lines (45m)

```
buff = shply_line.buffer(45)
```

Select the points within 45m (point in polygon):

```
from geopandas.tools import sjoin
buff = gpd.GeoDataFrame( geometry=[buff])
pointInPolys = sjoin(point,buff, how='left')
pointInPolys
   id                  geometry                      index_right
0   1  POINT (165.2232667307835 -581.6023098314181)          NaN
1   2  POINT (458.0395231332805 -626.3180927932262)          0.0
2   3  POINT (807.1111194563855 -509.4800791162997)          NaN
3   4  POINT (1019.150477463845 -1181.659268662333)          NaN
4   5  POINT (74.34925616221153 -244.0702704396099)          0.0
5   6  POINT (19.53636085704784 -383.9873978914693)          0.0
point45 = pointInPolys.dropna()
point45
   id                  geometry                      index_right
1   2  POINT (458.0395231332805 -626.3180927932262)          0.0
4   5  POINT (74.34925616221153 -244.0702704396099)          0.0
5   6  POINT (19.53636085704784 -383.9873978914693)          0.0
result2 =  point45.copy()
result2['geometry'] = result2.apply(lambda row:    shply_line.interpolate(shply_line.project( row.geometry)), axis=1)
print(result2)
   id                  geometry                      index_right
1   2  POINT (433.554325720973 -616.258892163531)          0.0
4   5  POINT (74.34925616221147 -233.4585492227979)          0.0
5   6  POINT (18.88030104343747 -405.9654016474183)          0.0
```

Points in Green

[image]

Comment: how do i apply the 45m snapping distance to the interpolate function? Only the closest point within 45m can be snapped to a line segment. Therefore, only 1 point can be snapped to a line segment.

Comment: Look at New in the answer.

Comment: i edited my question with a picture to show multiple bus stops (green) near a road (brown). Only the closest bus stop within the 45m buffer must be snapped. There should only be 1 green dot on the brown line.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this can be done by yourself from the solution, It's easy

Comment: This code is very useful for snapping the points. Just a small clarification; I don't see any way to obtain measures of the line file. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It is another question

Comment: thank you! I already asked it here but it is on hold due to lack of clarity in question :( https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338928/linear-referencing-using-python-only

Comment: I do not see `result2` defined anywhere. Perhaps, `result2 = point.copy()`?

Comment: No it is `result2 = point45.copy()`. Thanks, corrected