# Linear Referencing using Python only

Tags: python, linear-referencing

I am using shapely to snap points to a line. This is the piece of code I use

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf_segments = gpd.read_file("line.shp")
shply_line = gdf_segments.geometry.unary_union
point  = gpd.read_file('points.shp')
result = point.copy()
result['geometry'] = result.apply(lambda row: shply_line.interpolate(shply_line.project( row.geometry)), axis=1)
```

How do I get the RID and MEAS values? These values are obtained on running the Locate Features along route linear referencing tool in ArcGIS Desktop.

I would like to achieve the above without arcpy or ArcGIS or FME. I want to code it entirely with python using gdal/ogr/shapely/fiona anything.

Code above referenced from: [Snap points shapefile to line shapefile using shapely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306838/snap-points-shapefile-to-line-shapefile-using-shapely)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an open source solution you could consider this QGIS plugin [LRS](https://blazek.github.io/lrs/)? If you look at the [help page](https://blazek.github.io/lrs/release/help.1.2.0/index.html) is appears to offer a UI and scripting solution.