# How to calculate mean of GPS data assigned to 30 m segment in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gps

I have collected some temperature data from a Google Car dataset with each data having Lat/Lon and temperature values. The data is stored in CSV file. I already fixed the GPS lat/lon by using "project" and "interpolate" using this shapely [Snap points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306838/snap-points-shapefile-to-line-shapefile-using-shapely).
[image: Snapped points]

I also have a shapefile of the road the car took divided into 30 m segments.[image: 30 m segment of road]

What I want to know, how can I snap/group GPS data to these 30 m segments in QGIS?

I am using QGIS 3.16 and all data is projected in ESPG 4326.

Comment: Please don't post two questions at once. Also, I am under the impression, that both issues have been dealt with on GIS.SE already.

Comment: Hey sorry, I am not aware on what exactly to find. I am really new to GIS domain and also using QGIS. You have any reference/link that will be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I realized that I can use "Join Attributes by Location (summary)" to calculate the some statistics for all the points lying on each 30 m line segment.

This answers my question.

But I have issue that I am not able to get values for all the line segments. The join only gives me statistics for few line segments.

Comment: You should not ask a question in an answer - it will go unnoticed. Rather ask a new question